# How did the newspaper know about Pavlov's research before he conducted it?

Tags: enola-holmes-2

In *Enola Holmes 2*, at approximately 31:45 into the movie, a newspaper is shown with an advertisement that seems to be a clear reference to [Ivan Pavlov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ivan_Pavlov)'s research on conditioning with dogs:

[image: Screenshot showing the newspaper with the Pavlov advertisement]

However, just a few seconds later, another newspaper is shown which has the date as December 31, 1885.

[image: Screenshot showing the newspaper with the 1885 date]

Per the linked Wikipedia page above, this would be a good 15 years before Pavlov published his research.

(The same Wikipedia page does mention that Pavlov studied in the Heidenhain laboratories from 1884 - 1886 and the area of study was dog digestion, but that research is not what Pavlov was famous for, nor does it really fit as the reference of the advertisement.)

How, then, can we explain how a newspaper from 1885 referenced something that hadn't happened yet?

Comment: Isn’t it likely to be a joke?

Comment: If I remember correctly, this poster is not portrayed as part of an actual scene but as a visual to support the narrator's text, ie. Enola Holmes who is telling her story. The book itself is written in the first person, past tense style. So an older Enola Holmes could know about Pavlov.